# Property 'theme' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)

Tags: typescript, themes, styled-components, intrinsicattributes

I am a junior in TypeScript, I am trying to create a dark mode in TypeScript, using styled-components and a custom hook.

useDarkMode.tsx

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export const useDarkMode = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('dark');

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    theme === 'dark' ? setTheme('light') : setTheme('dark');
  };

  return [theme, toggleTheme];
};
```

HeaderComponent.tsx

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { useDarkMode } from '../hooks';
import { ToggleTheme } from './';

const Header = styled.header`
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  &:after {
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: table;
  }
`;

export const HeaderComponent = () => {
  const [theme, toggleTheme] = useDarkMode();
  console.log(theme);
  return (
    <>
      <Header>
                   // ️ ERROR HERE
        <ToggleTheme theme={theme} />
      </Header>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Error here in the next image]

For some reason I get the following error:

```
(property) theme: any
Type '{ theme: any; toggleTheme: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'theme' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)
```

ToggleTheme.tsx

```
export const ToggleTheme = () => {
  return <div>ToggleTheme</div>;
};
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `ToggleTheme` component?

Comment: ToggleTheme.tsx added.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate cause of the error is that your `<ToggleTheme>` component has no such `theme` prop (nor `toggleTheme`).

Here I guess you would like to use that `<ToggleTheme>` component as a button to trigger your `toggleTheme` function?

In that case, you would just attach that function to the [`onClick`](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) attribute:

```
<ToggleTheme onClick={() => toggleTheme()} />
```

Comment: That's right @ghybs  Thank you so much for your help!
Now it works properly. 